# Write tags in HTML and print

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code to send a message from textarea after completion tags are sent as I wrote
 Not output, for example, I want to write

```
<h1> thanks </h1>
```

I need output at
Transmitter Thanks

instead of

```
<h1> thanks </h1>
```

> code from comment
>
> ```html
> <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label"> <textarea class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" rows="3" id="emailbody" data-required="true"></textarea> <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample5">Email body</label> </div>
> ```

Comment: kindly post your code then only we can help you.

Comment: Print Outputs
Tags I have a code to send a message from textarea after completion tags are sent as I wrote
Not output, for example, I want to write
<h1> thanks </h1>

I need output at
Transmitter Thanks

instead of

<h1> thanks </h1>

Comment: Kindly post your script code also.

Comment: <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
<textarea class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" rows="3" id="emailbody" data-required="true"></textarea>
<label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample5">Email body</label>
</div>

Comment: kindly refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you want this type of output.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".submit").click(function() { 
         var a = $(this).siblings(".mdl-textfield__input").val();
         if(a != ''){
           function stripHTML(text){
             var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
             return text.replace(regex, "");
           }
           var no_tags = stripHTML(a);
           $(".mdl-textfield__label").text("Your value is:"+no_tags);
           var a = $(this).siblings(".mdl-textfield__input").val("");
         }   
     });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label"> <textarea class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" rows="3" id="emailbody" data-required="true"></textarea><br><button class="btn submit btn-primary">Submit</button><br><label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample5"></label></div>
```